# Laravel 5.6 Hosting bootstrap/cache config.php how to change file path?

Tags: laravel, hosting

I tried to deploy my website to server using free webhost. somehow i get this error:

"file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\zuppDelivery\storage\framework/sessions/wUomPBtZex8v7R7xizGF1yZhy631uMIwylVnQKfl): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

this is due to config.php in my bootstrap/cache

https://i.stack.imgur.com/66uX0.png

how i can solve this? i tried to delete the config.php files but its not working.

Comment: Could you search for `zuppDelivery` in your whole project?

Comment: in server hosting or what?

Comment: no, your whole projects files. It must be written somewhere. Also, check the `.env` file on your server.

Comment: i don't think the path of the file should be in "C:/" folder. Should i change the path in the server? the server has two file one for public_html and another one laravel. zuppdelivery is my project name in htdocs in xampp. Thank you for spending time for answering this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the problem is the **ABSOLUTE PATH**, which can be found on `/your-project-directory/bootstrap/cache/config.php`, there is a bunch of absolute paths there and all you must do is changing them to your current absolute path on the server.

to do that automatically use the command `php artisan config:cache`, but, since you are doing that in production make sure you read the Documentation at **https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#configuration-caching**

Answer (score 0):

shared hosting does not show full path of your  [project folder]in shared hosting and  if you want clear cache , you have to purchase their plugins. by the given solution you have no need to purchase any plugin or no need to clear / config cache of laravel 5.6 or more.

1. hit the URl in your browser it will give you error log. now oprn your error log and **copy the path** from the error log.
2. change all file paths in config.php of [your project folder ]/bootstrap/cache,  [your project folder ]\bootstrap\cache or [your project folder ]\* etc by the full path copied from error log like /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/411797/622471/[yourdomain]/web/content/[your project folder ]